# Node.js подключение к mongodb, переполнение памяти

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Сервер Linux Debian 7.
Есть два приложения на node.js оба подключаются к mongodb.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', function (err, db) { 
    if (err) {
        helper.log('Mongodb connection error', 425, err); 
        return 0;
    }

userListDB = db.collection('users');
activityDB = db.collection('activity ');
g_Mongoconnected = true;
helper.msg('mongodb connected');
});
```

Сделал вывод что из того-что приложения подключаются отдельно идет переполнение памяти (3гб за 20 часов) если не перезагружать приложение то они попросту зависают когда озу заканчивается.
Если запустить только 1 приложений таких проблем не наблюдается.
Так же каждое приложение использует свой набор модулей из node_modules в том числе и mongodb?
Можно ли сделать 1 подключение на 2 приложения или как еще можно решить проблему с переполнением памяти?

Comment: Скорее всего дело не в количестве подключений, виноват плохо написанный код. Например, объявление функций внутри циклов или обработчиков событий. **Попробуйте прикрутить мониторинг потребления ресурсов, вроде [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) +логирование и смотрите динамику потребления памяти.** Гоняйте приложение тестами и смотрите при каких тестах память начинает "протекать" особо активно, эти куски потом анализируйте отдельно. Без подобной информации ни нам, ни вам проблему не решить

Comment: @MiKeBu Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Причина

Скорее всего дело не в количестве подключений, виноват плохо написанный код.

Рост потребления памяти - следствие того, что память выделяется приложению, но не возвращается обратно. Маловероятно, что причина - несколько приложений, подключенных к одной базе, это обычная ситуация. Гораздо проще можно добиться роста занятой памяти просто неаккуратным кодом, например, объявляя функции внутри циклов или обработчиков часто вызываемых событий. Отдельно запущенные приложения, возможно, тоже протекали, но делали это менее заметными темпами

**Основное подозрение - неаккуратный код.**

**[ ! ]** Возможно, плохо написан не код вашего проекта, а сторонний npm-модуль (адаптер БД в первую очередь под подозрением) или даже кусок ядра Node.js.

#### Решение:

"Разделяя и властвуя", найдите места, где происходит утекание памяти и ликвидируйте дырки. Возможные меры:

- Проверьте утечки, если БД находится на другой машине
- Проверьте утечки на других версиях Node.js
- Используйте отладчик, например [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector), коллеги хвалили
- Прикрутите [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) или аналогичные мониторы ресурсов
- Регулярно выводите в логи `process.memoryUsage()`
- Прогоняйте одни и те же действия приложения в течении 2-3 минут и смотрите, сколько памяти утекло при выполнении этого кода